# Cannot convert the datetime to char in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query in SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id,Name,Date, WeekOffDate 
FROM tblEmployee 
LEFT JOIN tblWeekOff
```

So clearly, `Id` and `Name` come from `tblEmployee` and `WeekOffDate` comes from `tblWeekOff`.

Now, in the `Date` column, I am writing this piece of query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Id, Name, 
    (CASE WHEN Date = WeekOffDate THEN 'WO' END) 
FROM tblEmployee
```

But I get this error saying:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

So I to overcome this error, I tried this

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Id, Name, 
    (CASE WHEN CAST(Date AS nvarchar) = CAST(WeekOffDate AS nvarchar) THEN 'WO')
FROM tblEmployee
```

i.e. I tried casting. Similarly I tried `CONVERT()` function, but no luck.

My goal is to show the "WO" status where the date matches with the `WeekOffDate` in a table. But I am really surprised why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

The WeekOffDate data looks like this:

[image: WeekOffDate]

Where am I lacking?

Comment: sorry, let me add the tag I am using MS SQL Server

Comment: What are the **data types** for the `tblEmployee.Date` and the `tblWeekOff.WeekOffDate` columns?

Comment: Could you give us an example of WeekOffDate data ?

Comment: @marc_s, it is Datetime for both

Comment: Could you try this.

(CASE WHEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), Date , 103)  = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), WeekOffDate , 103) THEN 'WO' END)

Comment: @ismetguzelgun, the query went successfully, but the results are not shown. It shows a warning saying:  Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: @ismetguzelgun, actually the Date is a dynamic PIVOT date that comes from database.I cannot put the entire PIVOT query here as it would be too long to show.

Comment: What do you want to show date or weekoffdate? You can add column to your select end edit your case with an else statement like  (CASE WHEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), Date , 103) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), WeekOffDate , 103) THEN 'WO' ELSE 'YES' END)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211631/discussion-between-ismetguzelgun-and-noobprogrammer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this.

```
(CASE WHEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATE)) , 103) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, WeekOffDate))  , 103) THEN 'WO' ELSE 'YES'END)
```

EDIT: Warning is nothing more than a warning in this case. It is just saying the fact. You can overcome this with adding an else statement in your case.

Comment: I tried your code, if I am adding else I am getting the error I mentioned, not otherwise.

Comment: I edited my answer. Would you check it ? @noobprogrammer